# Liquibase not updating column data type when changed in Entity class through Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

In the Spring Boot, Spring Data JPA project, I have an entity class named **Country** with few columns. I generated changelog and applied it with the following commands

```
$ mvn process-test-resources

$ mvn process-resources
```

It created tables using liquibase and liquibase-hibernate5 plugins

**Country.java**

```
package com.liquibasedemo.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
@Table(name = "country")
@Data
public class Country
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "iso_code")
    private String isoCode;

    @Column(name = "test_code")
    private String testCode;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "region_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Region region;

}
```

I updated `testCode` column data type from Long to String in Country class and used the above commands to generate changeset. After applying changeset, the datatype remains unchanged. Here is the pom.xml file

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibasedemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>liquibasedemo</name>
    <description>Liquibase Demo project with Spring Boot and Spring Data</description>

    <properties>
        <spring-boot.version>2.1.5.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.4.3.Final</hibernate.version>
        <liquibase-maven-plugin.version>3.5.5</liquibase-maven-plugin.version>
        <liquibase-hibernate5.version>3.6</liquibase-hibernate5.version>
        <validation-api.version>2.0.1.Final</validation-api.version>
        <javassist.version>3.24.0-GA</javassist.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${liquibase-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                    <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/db/db.changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
                    <diffChangeLogFile>src/main/resources/db/changelog/${maven.build.timestamp}_changelog.xml</diffChangeLogFile>
                    <logging>info</logging>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>update-profile</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>update</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>diff-profile</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>diff</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                        <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate5</artifactId>
                        <version>${liquibase-hibernate5.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                        <version>${validation-api.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                        <version>${javassist.version}</version>
                    </dependency>

                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: how does the changeset look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This generation of changeset using `liquibase-hibernate5` does not include the field type changes. If you can see into the `changeset` file you will not find the `changeset` generated regarding your field type change. It seems to be not supported by the `liquibase-hibernate5` plugin.

1. Have a look at the comments in this [class](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/blob/master/src/main/java/liquibase/ext/hibernate/diff/ChangedColumnChangeGenerator.java)
2. The developer of this plugin is discussing about it at [link](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/issues/48#issuecomment-238380616)

   > The reason these tend to be ignored is because how hibernate
   >   represents the datatype is usually different than how the database
   >   represents the datatype even when they are actually the same. I'm
   >   looking at ways to improve this with Liquibase 4.
3. Solution for now would be to add the `diff` manually. The following code is taken from [link](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/modify_data_type.html)

   ```
   <changeSet author="liquibase-docs" id="modifyDataType-example">
       <modifyDataType catalogName="cat"
               columnName="id"
               newDataType="int"
               schemaName="public"
               tableName="person"/>
   </changeSet>
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am still surprised it's not implemented in 2019.

Answer (score 0):

you can just add ChangeSet to your xml file ( in case you'are using xml and not yaml or another file type).

```
<changeSet id="change type" author="me">
    <modifyDataType tableName="Country" columnName="name" 
           newDataType="VARCHAR(255)"/>
</changeSet>
```

For more like adding , renaming and dropping column you can view this link :
[Liquibase spring boot maintain database schema changes](https:///codeanystuff.com/liquibase-spring-boot-maintain-database-schema-changes/)
I hope that's help